# Syntax Error: Unexpected Token in a Loop Program

Tags: javascript

When I use this code, a syntax error (unexpected token) pops up. Being new to JavaScript, I can't pinpoint what the issue is.

```
    var a = 1;

var test = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     a++;
     console.log(a);
    };

    do{
     a = 2;
     console.log(a);

     while(a===2){
        a--;
        console.log(a);
     };
    };
};

function test();
```

Comment: The issue is an unexpected token. Which token is unexpected?

Comment: You don't need `function` if you are trying to invoke `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want this:

(beware: running this results in an infinite loop outputting `2` in the console)

```
var a = 1;

var test = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a++;
        console.log(a);
    };

    do{
        a = 2;
        console.log(a);

    } while(a===2){
        a--;
        console.log(a);
    };
};

test();
```